# No route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for, controllers

I'm building a Rails app and am making a form with form_for. I keep getting the error that there are no route matches for what I've specified, but when I run rake routes, I see the route I'm specifying (or at least I think I do). Can anyone help out?

My form_for tag is:

```
<%=form_for @party, :url => { :action => "update", :controller=>"parties", :method=>"patch" } do |f| %>
```

And in my parties controller I have:

```
  def update
    @party.find(params[:id])
    @party.update_attributes

   if @party.save
     redirect_to '/login'
    end
  end
```

Also, my routes for the party model are seen below:
[image]

Comment: Try this: `<%=form_for @party, :url => { :action => "update", :controller=>"parties"}, :method=>"patch" do |f| %>`

Comment: I get the same error message. Also same thing if I try "put" instead of "patch!"

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error ?

Comment: app/views/application/_rsvp.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_application__rsvp_html_erb__1942726801474912626_70323230539220'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Comment: Change to update..not patch

Comment: Can you provide the full error with stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

If you leave out the options, rails will figure out if it is a create/update form. Otherwise you will need to have separate forms for create/update if you specify options.

```
<%= form_for @parties do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```